# about django templates and global variables

Tags: django, templates, variables, global

I have a skeleton.html template, and i have a archives box in my blog. So i have to update in every function in my views or there is one simple way to do that? like a global variable takes the latest and the newest post's year then i will use in my templates?

And when i extend another template like:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}

{% block css %}<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}"/>{% endblock %}

{% block contentRight %}
<div id="search">
    <h2>Search</h2>
    <form action="#" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="searchbox"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="archives">
    <h2>Archives</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">2013</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2012</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2011</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

title is in my views.py home function, when i create another html file and extend index and pass the title block it loads nothing...
sry for my bad english and noobish question~im new in django

Comment: django custom template tag? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **define your own** [RequestContext processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext), query the years you want in `years_processor`:

```
def years_processor(request):
    return {'years': range(2013, 2010, -1)}
```

Add it to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`, then use `years` **directly in your every template**.

```
<ul>
    {% for year in years %}
        <li><a href="#">{{ year }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Keep in mind that **you should use** `render` or pass context explictly.

Comment: i can add al my custom requestcontext variables at one func? that will bi effective for speed or else?

Comment: @user3289406 You can specify context_instance.

Comment: can you show an example? (and i meant like def processors(request): then all my variables will go there i asked for it)

Comment: @user3289406 Have you seen the link I provided in the answer?Find `some_view` in that page.

Comment: so u can say i can use my processors in my other function in my views?  i tried but it failed

Comment: @user3289406 Have you imported them(processors)?